# function doesn't respect closure

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to execute a function for each item in array, i'm aware of the closure and compensating for this by using the ES6 `let` and tried using `forEach` as following:

```
       this.tourIDS = [];
         this.tours.forEach(tour => {
         this.tourIDS.push(tour.tour_id);
       });

       this.tourIDS.forEach(id => {
         this.map.setFilter('routes', ['==', 'tour_id', id]);
           console.log(id);
       });
```

this is mapboxgl `setFilter` function that takes a query parameter like this `['==', 'tour_id', id]`, the idea here is to pass the id from the `tourIDS` array once for each id it contains.
so the expected behavior is to have the function executed on every element in the array but only the last element in the array is what gets executed same as if there was no closure however the `console.log(id)` gets executed right logging each element, so why would `console.log` works and another function don't ?!

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Surely `this.map.setFilter(` is going to replace the existing filter each time, as such makes total sense it's the last one applied.

Comment: @Keith oh ! so you mean that the function is executing right but each time it runs the filter overwrite the previous one ?! so at the end you find only the last id.

Comment: Yes, looking at the docs you need to build up another array, maybe using the `all` directive.  https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#other-filter

Comment: oh god, thank you for such important note, but if i added the "all" condition is this will accumulate the filters each time the function executes ?

Comment: Only call the set filter once, just build up the parameters into an array first.  ps. `all` is also the equivalent to `AND`, so it you might want the `any` option instead, that's similar to `OR`

Comment: ok i understand, i was going to find another way to set this filter but the question here was intended as i thought that something wrong with the closure. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Keith emphasized in his comment, this is not something wrong with the loop but with the nature of the mapbox-gl js `setFilter` itself as recalling the function overwrites the previous filter.